# how to insert values from toggle button to database without submit button

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to update values in the database using toggle button 
Here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input.status').on('change', function () {
       var decision = $(this).val();
       var id = $('td.myvalue').html();     
        alert(decision);
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/CodeIgniter/users/Users/update",
        data: {decision: decision, id: id},
        success: function (msg) {

        $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
       }
    })
  });
});
```

DataTable

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover DataTables "id="DataTables" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Icon</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Group Users</th>
            <th>Status</th>
             <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $i = 0;
            foreach ($getTableGroup as $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="myvalue">
                <?= $value->id ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $value->group_name ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="tagsinput form-control" type="text" value="sam"/>
            </td>
            <input class="myid" type="hidden" value="<?= $value->id ?>"/> 
            <td >
                <?php if ($value->group_status == 'on'): ?>
                <div class="switch">
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox status" id="example<?= $i ?>" name="group-status" >
                        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example<?= $i ?>">
                            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php elseif ($value->group_status == 'off'): ?>
                <div class="switch">
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox status" id="example<?= $i ?>" name="group-status">
                        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example<?= $i ?>">
                            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $i++;
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My code is working fine but the issue is in scripting section where when I click on toggle button the id does not increase every time id came in the alert box is 1 but in datatable it show the Id number from database

Comment: It might be useful to see the `/CodeIgniter/users/Users/update` script

Comment: i didn't ask how to update its a question related top some logic of script and php not related to query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your always fetching first `td` value `$('td.myvalue')` It's wrong  you need to fetch the currently changed  `tr td` value like this

```
 var id = $('td.myvalue').html(); //it will always return the first td only .
```

Change to

```
var id = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('td').parent('tr').find('td.myvalue').html();
```

Comment: it says undefined in alert box now

Comment: works! can you explain how this works  and any other clean way to do this thing ?

Comment: I think this is the right way to do this . Read about Dom traverse in jquery  @AbdullahFraz

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to reduce more parent.

```
var id =  $(this).closest('tr').find('td.myvalue').text();
```